# How to avoid abnormal changes in the time zone when using POSIXct?

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I am using POSIXct to convert my datetime. Once the data is read from the file I use the following:

```
DF$datetime <- as.POSIXct(DF$datetime, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", "EET")
```

The problem comes when the time changes from EEST to EET. My data changes as following:

```
2018-10-28 03:25:00 EEST
2018-10-28 from 03:26:00 until 03:59:00 as EET
2018-10-28 from 03:00:00 until 03:25:00 as EEST
2018-10-28 03:26:00 EET
```

If I use UTC instead of EET it works fine. Any suggestion how can I avoid this situation?

Comment: You have to stay in UTC as (essentially) _all other_ timezones have day light savings.  There is a reason log files and records use UTC -- it is absolute.  All others are relative.

Comment: Yes, I agree to work with the UTC. I just want to avoid those 2 Time Zone changes in my data when I use Easter Europe Time. It must be only 1, from EEST at 03:25:00 to EET at 03:26:00. Actually, the Tz should be EEST until 03:59:00 , then when the clock starts again the hour 03:00:00 this now should have the EET, and not like the data above.